# JQuery autocomplete result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

Hello I am using autocomplete to allow users to search venues stored in a MySQL database. The autocomplete plugin is currently listing the venues when the user begins typing and prints the selected venue using the result handler.

I would like to also print the address, phone number and website of the venue as well but I am not sure how to do this.

I have the autocomplete plugin running a php script to print out the venue names from the database. I am not sure how to retrieve the other fields in the database without displaying the autocomplete input field...

This is what I have so far:

**JQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").autocomplete("search.php", {width: 260, selectFirst: false}).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    $("#result").html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
$search = $_GET['q'];
    $search = "%".$search."%";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT club_name FROM clubs WHERE club_name LIKE '$search'") or die('Something is wrong');
        while($value = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $club = $value[club_name];
            echo "$club\n";
        }
```

The php above only select the club name because when I try to select more fields they display in the search results on the JQuery side.

I am new to JQuery so I am a little lost... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, but this is the easiest:

You want to return the data from the server like this. The first column should contain the value you want to retrieve in the end:

```
title|address|phone|web
title|address|phone|web
title|address|phone|web
```

And then you want to use the [`formatItem` and `formatValue`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) callback in your autocomplete function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").autocomplete("search.php", {
        width: 260, 
        selectFirst: false,
        formatItem: function(row){
          var ret = '<span class="title">' + row[0] + '</span><br />';
          ret += '<span class="address">' + row[1] + '</span> ';
          ret += '<span class="phone">' + row[2] + '</span> ';
          ret += '<span class="web">' + row[3] + '</span> ';
          return ret;
        },
        formatValue: function(row){
          return row[0]; // We only want the first value to be searched
        }
      }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        $("#result").html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
      });
});
```

*Also, your are not escaping the input from the user and as such have a nasty vunerability for SQL injection*

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot. As for not escaping I am still testing the script so I will add the security features once it works.

Thanks again!

Comment: @mrdthomas Great! If it works for you be sure to come back and mark the answer as accepted so future searchers know it was correct... plus we both get rep points :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Doug Neiner, the code you supplied work wonderfully, Thanks!