# JQuery Autocomplete hidden field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, hidden, hidden-field

I received help on the first part of my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054403/jquery-autocomplete-result) whoever I forgot to mention my second issue. After a user selects a value from the autocomplete field I would like to populate the vaules ID into a hidden field so it can be passed to PHP and inserted into a database.

Here is a breakdown of what I am trying to accomplish:

1. User selects venue from autocomplete field.
2. After the venue has been selected, the venues phone, address and website are display under the autocomplete field. The ID of the record in the database is passed to a hidden field as its value.

I have search but found nothing. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you're using the standard autocomplete plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

If you have this in your html:

```
<input type='text' id='foo' />
<input type='hidden' id='bar' />
```

You will want to use this as your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    var data = "1,address 1,phone 1|2,address 2,phone 2".split('|');
    $("#foo").autocomplete(data,{formatItem:function(item){
        return item[0].split(',').slice(1).join(' ');}
    }).result(function(event,item){
        $("#bar").val(item[0].split(',')[0]);
    });
});
```

What you're doing is this:

1. Adding a formatItem option to
   take out the id from your source
   data.
2. Adding a result handler to
   set your hidden field with the id.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Jieren, I will give it a try later today and let you know the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Having hit this brick wall as well I think, with some help here, I have found an even simpler solution

```
  $("#fieldA").autocomplete({
    source: '<%=Url.Action("functionName", "ControllerName") %>',
    select: function(e,ui) { $('#fieldB').val(ui.item.objectName) }, 
  });
```

***fieldA*** does the autocomplete from the source file.  I'm using ASP.net MVC which takes the ***functionName*** inside of the ***ControllerName*** (of course you could just stick the URL of the web link you want as well).  The web page returns a list of rows broken down into separate item fields.  The only restriction is that at one of the fields returned is named "***value***".  The select then allows you to take apart all the other fields (the objectname on the end of ui.item) from the ui.item object and place in as many fields as you require while the "***value***" from the ***ui.item.value*** automatically fills in the autocomplete field.